# How to update cart quantity using ajax,jquery,php and sessions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am facing a problem updating the quantity of cart items,click the + or - button to increase or decrease the quantity of an item, the quantity of every item is affected.
Here is a screenshot of the page http://prntscr.com/7wc9ar

I have taken help from https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/04/shopping-cart-in-php.html in order to make this cart

Here is my code

**Cart.php**

```html
<?php
require_once("includes/initialize.php");
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$qty = isset($_SESSION['qty']) ? $_SESSION['qty'] : 1;

require_once("includes/header.php");

?>

    <section id="cart_items">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">Shopping Cart</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?php
    if ($action == 'removed') {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
        echo "<strong>{$name}</strong> was removed from your cart!";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    else if ($action == 'quantity_updated') {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
        echo "<strong>{$name}</strong> quantity was updated! {$qty}";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION["cart_items"]) && count($_SESSION['cart_items']) > 0)
    {

        // get the product ids
        $ids = "";
        foreach ($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $id => $value) {
            $ids = $ids . $id . ",";
        }

        // remove the last comma
        $ids = rtrim($ids, ',');
        ?>
        <div class="table-responsive cart_info">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                <tr class="cart_menu">
                    <td class="image">Item</td>
                    <td class="description"></td>
                    <td class="price">Price</td>
                    <td class="quantity">Quantity</td>
                    <td class="total">Total</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>


                <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN ({$ids}) ORDER BY productName";
                $result = $database->query($query);
                $total_price = 0;
                while ($row = $database->fetchArray($result)) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cart_product">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/products/<?php echo $row['productImageName'] ?>" height="100"
                                            width="100" alt=""></a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cart_description">
                            <h4><a href="#"><?php echo $row["productName"] ?></a></h4>

                            <p>Web ID: 1089772</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cart_price">
                            <?php $price = $row["productPrice"] ?>
                            <p>PKR <?php echo $price ?></p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cart_quantity">
                            <div class="cart_quantity_button">
                                <?php
                                $id = $row["id"];
                                $name = $row["productName"];
                                ?>
                                <a class="cart_quantity_down" href="<?php echo "decreaseQty.php?id={$id}&name={$name}&qty={$qty}"; ?>"> - </a>
                                <!--<a class="cart_quantity_down" href=""> - </a>-->

                                <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['qty']; ?>"
                                       autocomplete="off" size="2">
                                <a class="cart_quantity_up" href="<?php echo "increaseQty.php?id={$id}&name={$name}&qty={$qty}"; ?>"> + </a>
                                <!--<a class="cart_quantity_up" href=""> + </a>-->
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cart_total">
                            <p class="cart_total_price">PKR <?php echo $price * $qty ?></p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cart_delete">
                            <?php
                            $id = $row["id"];
                            $name = $row["productName"];
                            echo "<a href='removeFromCart.php?id={$id}&name={$name}' class='cart_quantity_delete'><i class=\"fa fa-times\"></i></a>";
                            ?>
                            <!--<a class="cart_quantity_delete" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $total_price += $price * $qty;
                }

                ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
        echo "<strong>No products found</strong> in your cart!";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    </section> <!--/#cart_items-->

    <section id="do_action">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="heading">
                <h3>What would you like to do next?</h3>

                <p>Choose if you have a discount code or reward points you want to use or would like to estimate your
                    delivery cost.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="chose_area">
                        <ul class="user_option">
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <label>Use Coupon Code</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <label>Use Gift Voucher</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <label>Estimate Shipping & Taxes</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="user_info">
                            <li class="single_field">
                                <label>Country:</label>
                                <select>
                                    <option>United States</option>
                                    <option>Bangladesh</option>
                                    <option>UK</option>
                                    <option>India</option>
                                    <option>Pakistan</option>
                                    <option>Ucrane</option>
                                    <option>Canada</option>
                                    <option>Dubai</option>
                                </select>

                            </li>
                            <li class="single_field">
                                <label>Region / State:</label>
                                <select>
                                    <option>Select</option>
                                    <option>Dhaka</option>
                                    <option>London</option>
                                    <option>Dillih</option>
                                    <option>Lahore</option>
                                    <option>Alaska</option>
                                    <option>Canada</option>
                                    <option>Dubai</option>
                                </select>

                            </li>
                            <li class="single_field zip-field">
                                <label>Zip Code:</label>
                                <input type="text">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <a class="btn btn-default update" href="">Get Quotes</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default check_out" href="">Continue</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="total_area">
                        <ul>
                            <?php
                            if(!isset($total_price))
                            {
                                $total_price = 0;
                            }
                            ?>
                            <li>Cart Sub Total <span>PKR <?php echo $total_price ?></span></li>
                            <li>Eco Tax <span>NO Tax</span></li>
                            <li>Shipping Cost <span>PKR 200</span></li>
                            <?php
                            if($total_price == 0)
                            {
                                $total_price = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $total_price += 200;
                            }
                            ?>
                            <li>Total <span>PKR <?php echo $total_price ?></span></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a class="btn btn-default update" href="">Update</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default check_out" href="">Check Out</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!--/#do_action-->

<?php require_once("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

**increaseQty.php**

```html
<?php
require_once("includes/initialize.php");

// get the product id
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$qty = isset($_GET['qty']) ? $_GET['qty'] : "";

$qty++;
$_SESSION['qty'] = $qty;

reDirectTo("cart.php?action=quantity_updated&id=" . $id . '&name=' . $name.'&qty=' . $qty);
?>
```

**decreaseQty.php**

```html
<?php
require_once("includes/initialize.php");

// get the product id
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$qty = isset($_GET['qty']) ? $_GET['qty'] : "";

$qty--;

$_SESSION['qty'] = $qty;

reDirectTo("cart.php?action=quantity_updated&id=" . $id . '&name=' . $name.'&qty=' . $qty);
?>
```

Please help me to solve this quantity updating issue. If it cannot be handled through sessions then please guide me to a different solution.

Comment: You have 1 session variable called `qty`. You need to be storing quantity per item.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is no quantity based on a particular product. The quantity is assigned to the session variable `$_SESSION['qty']`. If you want to store the cart items based on individual product based. You should save that using an array of information.

For eg.

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array(
  $productid => array(
           'product_name' => $productname,
           'productId' => $productid,
           'quantity' => $productquantity
  ),
);
```